# Pandas Group By, Aggregate, Then Return A Different Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas DataFrame containing baseball fielding statistics. Each row shows how many games a player has appeared at a given position over the course of his career.

| Player | Position | Games |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Brock Holt | 2B | 20 |
| Brock Holt | 3B | 70 |
| Ben Zobrist | OF | 100 |
| Ben Zobrist | 2B | 15 |

I want to be able to return one row per player containing the position they played the most over the years. In the example above the resulting DataFrame would be:

| Player | Position |
| --- | --- |
| Brock Holt | 3B |
| Ben Zobrist | OF |

I've been attempting to group by Player and aggregate by Games like so

```
df.groupby('Player').agg({'Games':['max']})
```

which simply provides the name of the player and the maximum number of games played at a position and

```
df.groupby('Player')['Position'].agg({'Games':['max']})
```

which returns the error `"nested renamer is not supported."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transform `max` and use `eq` to create a boolean mask where True corresponds to the most played Games row for each player. Then filter `df`:

```
msk = df.groupby('Player')['Games'].transform('max').eq(df['Games'])
out = df[msk].drop(columns='Games')
```

Output:

```
        Player Position
1   Brock Holt       3B
2  Ben Zobrist       OF
```

Comment: This works great and I'm marking as the correct answer. I'm curious how you would go about handling ties?

Comment: @BenjaminFranklinGates if there are ties, this catches them all. If you want all positions in one row for each player, you can `groupby` again and aggregate them in a list or just join them as strings etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use groupby and max directly as below:

```
df.groupby(['Player']).max()
```

Yields:

```
           Position Games
Player      
Ben Zobrist OF      100
Brock Holt  3B      70
```

Comment: Careful: this computes, for each player, the maximum value of `Position`, and independently, the maximum value of `Games`! The result just happens to match the correct output because for Ben Zobrist, `OF` evaluates as larger than `2B` and 100 is larger than 15, and similarly, Brock Holt's maximum `Position` value of `3B` and his independently calculated maximum `Games` value of 70 both happen to occur in the same row together.

Comment: Good point, I had not considered the ramifications carefully enough